# pagination in mongodb avoid skip() and limit()

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new in nodejs, i want to search in big data, how can i search a document without using skip() and limit(), my database structure is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d1836d2596d624873c84f"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-03-05T10:13:10.248Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-05T10:13:10.248Z"),
    "phone" : "+92333333",
    "country_code" : "+92",
    "verified_user" : false,
    "verification_code" : "2951",
    "last_shared_loc_time" : ISODate("2018-03-05T10:13:10.240Z"),
    "share_loc_flag_time" : ISODate("2018-03-05T10:13:10.240Z"),
    "share_location" : true,
    "deactivate_user" : false,
    "profile_photo_url" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

how can i search using createdAt.
i need a mongodb query, which request to api and show that users

Comment: any reason to avoid `skip` and `limit` because that is the only way to do pagination mostly

Comment: fast and efficiency issue

Comment: You can maintain a field with the unique value and in sorted order. So a simple find query with a range like get data from db were id is `$gt` some value and `$lt` some value wil fetch the result.

Comment: using `skip()` is not recommended in big data on mongodb because always requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection, you can use `_id` indexe with `limit()` to do pagination

Comment: can you please give mein query guide?

Answer (score 1):

Using `skip()` is not recommended when we have big data in MongoDB because always requires the server to walk from the beginning of the collection, you can use `_id` index with `limit()` to do pagination, because `_id` field is indexed by default in MongoDB so you can use this field for a good performance.

For the first page you need to get `_id` value of the last document with `limit()` :

```
db.users.find().limit(8);

last_id = id;
```

Secondly for the next page compare this last `_id` value with next `_id` :

```
 db.users.find({'_id' > last_id}).limit(8);
```

For example assuming first `_id` equal to `1000` so :

```
                1000 < 1008  ==> PAGE 1 where last_id=1008
                1008 < 1016  ==> PAGE 2 where last_id=1016
                1016 < 1024  ==> PAGE 3 where last_id=1024
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  uid : 1,
  name: 'abc'
  ...
} 
{
  uid : 2,
  name: 'abc'
  ...
}
....
{
  uid : 10,
  name: 'abc'
  ...
}
{
  uid : 11,
  name: 'abc'
  ...
}
```

Now you can query like get data where `uid > 0` and `uid <5`

then in next slot it is get data where `uid > 5` and `uid <10`   like wise ...

May be this approcah can help you out